# Uso do _set no django framework

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, django-queryset

Estou seguindo o [tutorial do framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/intro/tutorial02/) porem me perdi no uso do comando `_set` do shell inicializado por `python manager.py shell`.
A sequencia dos comandos é a seguinte:

```
from polls.models import Choice, Question
q = Question.objects.get(pk=1)
q.choice_set.all()
q.choice_set.create(choice_text='Not much', votes=0)
q.choice_set.create(choice_text='The sky', votes=0)
```

*models.py*

```py
import datetime

from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone

class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.question_text

    def was_published_recently(self):
        return self.pub_date >= timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days = 1)

class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default = 0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.choice_text
```

---

A minha duvida é, porque `choice` antes do _set? Como que funciona exatamente esse comando? O `q.` no começo é para atribuir a Question *q* ao campo do tipo `models.ForeignKey`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O padrão `<modelo>_set` ou [`default_related_name`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/options/#django.db.models.Options.default_related_name) essencialmente é responsável por fazer a relação reversa de um (seu objeto `q` instanciado da classe `Question`) para muitos (0 ou mais objetos criados da classe `Choice` associados à instância da classe `Question` por relação de [`ForeignKey`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey)).

Resumindo, quando é estabelecida a relação de chave estrangeira (ou `ForeignKey` supracitada) no modelo `Choice` apontando para o modelo `Question` automaticamente é estabelecida uma relação de um para muitos a partir da propriedade `choice_set` (*choice* sendo baseado no nome do modelo adjacente, sempre em minúsculo) na instância `q`.

Como você observou originalmente, ao utilizar o método `q.choice_set.create` o objeto `q` estará sendo automaticamente injetado na criação dos objetos da classe relacionada (`Choice`); de forma análoga, ao acessar o método `q.choice_set.all` você estará informando ao *framework* que você deseja obter todos os objetos da classe `Choice` que estão relacionados à instância `q` especificamente.

É importante ressaltar que `Choice.objects.all` é diferente de `q.choice_set.all` neste caso: o primeiro estará obtendo *todos* os objetos da classe `Choice` sem filtrar a relação com a classe `Question`; já no segundo, conforme foi dito no parágrafo anterior, é basicamente estabelecido um filtro para obter apenas os dados relacionados à instância `q`.

Para exemplificar isso tudo, observe o seguinte caso:

```
from django.utils import timezone

# Criando um objeto Question
q = Question.objects.create(question_text='Que faz agora?', pub_date=timezone.now())

# Criando escolhas (Choice) relacionadas ao objeto Question
q.choice_set.create(choice_text='Programando', votes=0)
q.choice_set.create(choice_text='Jogando', votes=0)

'''
Demonstrando a criação de um novo objeto Question em que é definida
a associação diretamente na criação dos objetos Choice respectivos
'''
q2 = Question.objects.create(question_text='De onde fala?', pub_date=timezone.now())
Choice.objects.create(question=q2, choice_text='Brasil', votes=0)
Choice.objects.create(question=q2, choice_text='EUA', votes=0)
```

Finalmente, obtendo as `Choice`s, temos os seguintes resultados:

```
# Obtendo as escolhas (Choice) da pergunta (Question) 'Que faz agora?'
>>> q.choice_set.all()
<QuerySet [<Choice: Programando>, <Choice: Jogando>]>

# Mesma coisa para a pergunta 'De onde fala?'
>>> q2.choice_set.all()
<QuerySet [<Choice: Brasil>, <Choice: EUA>]>

# Obtendo os objetos Choice sem filtrar por qualquer dos Question relacionados
>>> Question.objects.all()
<QuerySet [<Choice: Programando>, <Choice: Jogando>, <Choice: Brasil>, <Choice: EUA>]>
```